# C++ For Loop: invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am trying to copy data from one vector to another but am getting an error , "Invalid operands to binary expression 'int' and 'Card' " when I try to compile the following for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= vectorOne[vecCapacity]; i++) { //step 3
                vectorTwo[i] = vectorOne[i];
   }
```

Would anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: How is defined vectorOne?

Comment: This should be a single call to `std::copy` or `std::copy_n`.

Comment: Can't use std::copy, this is a assignment with specific instructions. 

vectorOne is a T*, 
In an earlier function it is dynamically allocated, T*vector One; vectorOne = new T[vecCapacity]

Comment: So it's not even really a vector! Crikey.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you meant is

```
for (int i = 0; i <= vecCapacity; i++)
```

or even more likely

```
for (int i = 0; i < vecCapacity; i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message is clear enough: in this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i <= vectorOne[vecCapacity]; i++) { //step 3
                vectorTwo[i] = vectorOne[i];
   }
```

`i` has type `int` while `vectorOne[vecCapacity]` has type `Card` and there is no defined operator <= for these types.

So this loop makes no sense.

Maybe you mean

```
for (int i = 0; i < vecCapacity; i++) { //step 3
                vectorTwo[i] = vectorOne[i];
   }
```

Also take into account that you have to guarantee that the size of vectorTwo is not less than the size of vectorOne or at least `vecCapacity`.

You could use standard algorithm `std::copy` declared in header `<algorithm>`

For example

```
#include <algorithm>

//...

std::copy( vectorOne, vectorOne + vecCapacity, vectorTwo );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be looping from 0 to vectorOne's size.

```
for (int i = 0; i < vectorOne.size(); i++) { //step 3
                vectorTwo[i] = vectorOne[i];
   }`
`
```

Also, if you're doing it this way, make sure vectorTwo is big enough before the loop.

```
vectorTwo.resize(vectorOne.size());
```